# I can't properly return from a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

I have this code:

```
char* findFile(char* path, char* fileName)
{
DIR *thisDir;
struct dirent *dirEntry;

int notFound=1;

while (NULL != (dirEntry = readdir(thisDir)) && notFound)
{
    if (dirEntry->d_type == DT_DIR)
    {
        if (dirEntry->d_name[0] != '.')
        {
            char *nextPath = malloc(512);
            strcpy(nextPath, path);
            strcat(nextPath, dirEntry->d_name);
            nextPath[nextPathLen] = '/';
            findFile(nextPath, fileName);

        }
    }
    else if (dirEntry->d_type == DT_REG)
    {
        if (strcmp(fileName, dirEntry->d_name) == 0 )
        {
            char* foundPath = malloc (512);
            strcpy(foundPath,path);
            strcat(foundPath,fileName);
            notFound=0;
            return foundPath;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

At one point the function returns the `foundPath` but I don't know how to pick it up and return it from the first function call. I can print it to verity the function works, but what can I do to get that value from `foundPath` to use it in another function?

Comment: Look (or be inspired by) [ntfw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html). Since it is implemented by free software C standard libraries, you should look into their code (e.g. study appropriate source code of [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)...)

Comment: My guess would be this is the problem: `NULL != (dirEntry = readdir(thisDir)) && notFound`. Also, as the answer suggests, return. Also, you're leaking memory.

Comment: Probably more due to your obfuscating attempted implementation than anything else, the behaviour of your code is undefined since you're not returning a value on all control paths. What the deuce is `&& notFound` for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the line

```
findFile(nextPath, fileName);
```

with

```
char * f = findFile(nextPath, fileName);
if (f != NULL)
    return f;
```

You need to check the return value is not NULL - if it is NULL you want to keep looking.

You must also return NULL at the end of the function to indicate that nothing was found in that iteration. It is "undefined behaviour" to not have all code paths returning a value - that means anything could happen. Eg, you could get spurious addresses being returned instead of what you want in the case you don't find anything (which is to return NULL).

There are a few other issues - you'll have memory leaks with all those mallocs and no frees, but get it working first and then tackle that.

Comment: No worries! Don't forget to free the mallocs you don't need - they could add up to a lot if you are searching big directories. Eg, after `FindFile` returns you can free `nextPath`. Don't free `foundPath` inside your function - the caller will have to do that when it finishes processing what you returned.

Comment: This is weird, if I try to free(nextPath) after "char * f = findFile(nextPath, fileName);
if (f != NULL)", findFile it will return a null pointer.

Comment: `nextPath` gets copied in the recursive call, so in theory you no longer need it and should be able to free it on return. It may have something to do with `nextPath[nextPathLen] = '/';` Both  `strcpy` and `strcat` append the terminating `\0` for you. If you append another character, it's up to you to add the `\0` afterwards. You may be lucky - the char buffer may be filled with `\0` when it is allocated but you can't rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe doing this:

```
return findFile(nextPath, fileName);
```

Instead of:

```
findFile(nextPath, fileName);
```